# Graphics glitches on 22.04 with Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, wayland

I have a brand-new gaming laptop with an RTX 4060, which I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on yesterday. Upon logging in and changing the graphics driver from Nouveau to Nvidia proprietary, I encountered consistent graphical glitches after a few minutes of usage. They look like this:

[Large region of what looks like static obscuring the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq9Tu.jpg)

[Similar to above, but different region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wncv6.jpg)

The glitchy regions flicker and change when moving my mouse, alt-tabbing, etc. Eventually they get [more visually drastic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1EQI.jpg) (click for image), making the computer unusable. Sometimes it even hangs.

I tried reinstalling - no luck. Changing the display manager from Xorg to Wayland seemed to help, but the glitches still occurred after about 30 minutes of usage.

Interestingly, I attempted to screenshot the glitchy portions while on Xorg, and they showed up as all white in the image (despite looking very different on the screen itself).

This problem does not seem to occur in Windows, which by default uses the integrated graphics to render the desktop. This points to it being an Nvidia-related issue. I have verified that the issue occurs on Nvidia driver versions 525 and 530.

Note that I have not tested whether this issue occurs with Nouveau.

I did not encounter this issue when using 22.04 on my previous laptop, which had a GeForce MX250.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: what do the thermals look like from the lm-sensors package sensors report and the nvidia-settings thermal item, and nvidia-smi?

Comment: @ubfan1 nvidia-smi and nvidia-settings both report that the GPU is around 45-48 deg C.

Comment: Take a look at some GPU memory testers like MemtestCL  or MemtestG80.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712931/how-can-i-test-my-gpu-ram-integrity

Comment: @ubfan1 I ran memtest_vulkan for the Nvidia GPU and all seemed fine. But then at about 6 min into the test I experienced a white flash over part of the screen, and thereafter I could not move my cursor. The next line of output from memtest_vulkan reflected that everything was fine though.

Comment: @ubfan1 I also ran memtest_vulkan on the AMD iGPU, but my screen went black a few seconds in. Maybe the iGPU is actually the one being used to draw the desktop?

Comment: "Hybrid" Laptops let the Nvidia GPU do the major work, and let the internal GPU handle the display.  But sometimes things get turned around --  xrandr --listproviders shows the setup.  Nvidia as the "Source Output" is the "normal" state. If it's "Sink Output", things like the CUDA demos wont run.   Fix using env variables like:  __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia  ./oceanFFT  
Consider trying Ubuntu 23.04 for your new machine.